# Does Leaflet.js support SVG as the background?

Tags: svg, leaflet

I want to use SVG in the background with leaflet.js instead of a map. I know it supports SVG as markers, but I have no idea whether an SVG can be put in the background or not. Does someone has any experience with this?

Comment: Interesting idea. What's your use case that leads you to want to do this?